# remote debugging a shell extensions

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging, windows-shell

as every one know debugging a shell extension is not easy. and when Visual Studio supports remote debugging from one computer to another, can i use this feature to debug shell extensions on the remote machine. if yes, how can i deploy it to the remote machine with VS.

Comment: You need to install the Remote Debugging Monitor on the remote machine, then on the machine you want to debug from, connect to the remote machine and attach to explorer.exe.